# How to call a class with in constructor

Tags: java

I need a bit of clue on calling other classes within the constructor of a class. I'm not sure if its possible but I would be great if someone tell me how to do it, if possible.

I want to call a circle within the constructor of a player class.

```
public class Player {
     public Player() {
         Rectangle r = new rectangle(x,y,l,l);
     }
}
```

Comment: You just did it with Rectangle class

Comment: Did you try this? It should pretty much work as you've described (other than the `rectangle` constructor being lowercase). If you're hitting an error, post that.

Comment: "*I want to call a circle within the constructor of a player class*" - I might be mistaken, but `Rectangle` is a strange way to write `Circle`...

Comment: Note it should be uppercase: `new Rectangle(...)`, not `new rectangle(...)`.

Comment: What do you mean by *call a circle*? Do you want to create an instance of `Circle` like you did it with `Rectangle`? Or are you trying something different?

Answer (score 3):

You can use other classes within a constructor like you did in your sample with the `Rectangle` (it has to be `Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x,y,l,l)`)

but you have to take care, that your variable r is only available within your constructor. If you want to use that object within other methods you have to declare it outside. Same for the circle.

```
public class Player{
    Circle c;

   public Player(){
     c = new Circle(10);
   }

   public void someOtherMethod(){
     c.callSomeCircleMethod();
   }
}
```

Furthermore the variables `x,y,l` have to come from somewhere in your example.

Comment: it seems to work when I try to print something from that constructor but when I call the r(Rectangle obj) in main class where Pane and scene are available, the program runs without error but doesn't, render the rectangle on the screen

Comment: there are probably other things to consider if you are using a some framework to render or draw objects. usually there are certain render methods and you can call your rendering methods only within these methods of the framework.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it like Rectangle for example :

```
Circle circle = new Circle(10);
```